# Pandas: capitalize only certain strings in a column

Tags: pandas

I need to capitalize some words in a column, but not all.

Data sample:

```
Name      Dance
CHUNK     Truffle Shuffle
DATA      Gadget Shuffle
MOUTH     Goin Shoppin
COREYH    Aspirator shuffle
```

What I've tried:

```
caps_list = ['CHUNK','DATA','MOUTH']

mask = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x in caps_list)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].mask(mask).capitalize()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'capitalize'
```

Comment: What is your expected output? All caps for forst 3 rows?

Comment: `df.Name.mask(df.Name.isin(caps_list),df.Name.str.capitalize())` or `df.Name=np.where(df.Name.isin(caps_list),df.Name.str.capitalize(),df.Name)`

Comment: Sorry -- I'll edit the question. But yes, that is the expected output.

Comment: @anky_91 That worked, thank you! I was way off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
df.Dance = np.where(df['Name'].isin(caps_list ),df.Dance.str.capitalize(),df.Dance)
```